# Objective-C variables read as null in C++

Tags: c++, objective-c, objective-c++

I'm writing a cross-platform application and need to pass across `argc` and `argv` from Objective-C in Xcode to my generic argument handler class in C++. I have a global pointer to this handler class which I set with a `new` command, but because I can't do `new` in Objective-C I'm trying the following:

I have a header file called `MacCommandLineArgs.h` which contains only the following:

```
static int cmdlArgc = 0;
static const char** cmdlArgv = NULL;
```

I then set these from within `main.m`:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    cmdlArgc = argc;
    cmdlArgv = (const char**)argv;
    return NSApplicationMain(argc, (const char **)argv);
}
```

Once the Objective-C++ section of the application has been entered, I try to read back these global variables in order to pass them to the pure-C++ class:

```
int argc = cmdlArgc;
const char** argv = cmdlArgv;
globalCommandLineArgs = new CCommandLineArgs(argc, argv);
```

When stepping through with the debugger, `cmdlArgc` and `cmdlArgv` show up as valid data but `argc` and `argv` are still 0 and NULL after the assignment. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Do you read them in the same file? Please give more context to the reading code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't show how `cmdlArgc` and `cmdlArgv` are *declared*; it's surely in a header file, but what does it look like?.

Nothing outside of `main.m` will have access to those variables as they have been defined `static`, which leads me to wonder why you aren't getting linker errors.  I have concluded that the declaration of the of `cmdlArgc` and `cmdArgv` is something like this:

```
int cmdlArgc;
const char** cmdlArgv;
```

rather than this:

```
extern int cmdlArgc;
extern const char** cmdlArgv;
```

So every implementation file that includes the header will get their own copy, which is why it's `0`/`NULL`.

The solution is to drop the use of `static` in `main.m` and start using `extern` in the header.

However it's still an ugly pattern and I would think the very best solution is to rename `main.m` to `main.mm` and initialise `CCommandLineArgs` in `main()`, which is both clean and simple.

Comment: The initialisation of `cmdlArgc` and `cmdlArgv` is the declaration as well. However, I did change main.m to main.mm and that seems to solve it. Thanks!